# Bibliography compilation error with biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, compiling

After starting to use biblatex library from bibtex files can not be compiled any more.

Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,natbib=true,sortcites=true, block=space]{biblatex}
\bibliography{item}
\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{helbing_stochastic_1996} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\printbibliography[title=Works Cited] %(5)
\end{document}}
```

And here is my bibliography file:

```
@article{helbing_stochastic_1996,
    title = {A stochastic behavioral model and a ‘microscopic’foundation of evolutionary game theory},
    volume = {40},
    number = {2},
    journal = {Theory and decision},
    author = {Helbing, D.},
year = {1996},
pages = {149–179}
}
```

Footnote citation is very important for me so using biblatex is essential.

Comment: Your example works fine for (miktex 2.9, pdflatex, bibtex). It would be a good idea if you would tell us what didn't work (error messages, log-files) and how you actually compiled.

Answer (score 2):

How biblatex handles characters depends on what backend you use (BiBTeX or biber), see section 2.4.3 "Sorting and Encoding Issues" in the manual for details.

The reference works if you change

```
title = {A stochastic behavioral model and a ‘microscopic’foundation of evolutionary game theory},
```

to

```
title = {A stochastic behavioral model and a 'microscopic' foundation of evolutionary game theory},
```

Also note that you have a `}` too much at the last line of the LaTeX file even if it does not break compilation.

Comment: Does that mean that `biblatex` does not like e.g. backticks?